# How to get connection string in run-time with password in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

Here i am using appsettings.json file for connection string.
I got connection string in runtime without password.

Example:

```
((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection)DataContext.Database.GetDbConnection()).ConnectionString
```

Please help to get password in runtime.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why would you want the password? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you try skipping the DataContext and simply retrieve it from `Configuration.ConnectionStrings`?

Comment: I want to handle multiple server database simultaneously. That's why i get password on runtime.

Here i used this type of class. To get the records from different Server.
Example:
 public static DataTable GetDataTable(System.Data.CommandType commandType, string commandText, string Connectionstring)
{
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandText,
                Connectionstring);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
}

Comment: What you should be doing here is follow the Options pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, for security reasons. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> The ConnectionString is similar to an OLE DB connection string, but is not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is returned is the same as the user-set ConnectionString, minus security information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false (default). The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server does not persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.

So, try to add `Persist Security Info=true;` in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get the connection string from Configuration, not from a `DbConnection`. For example, if `appsettings.json` contains the following, you can get the connection string via `Configuration.GetConnectionString("mydb")`.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "mydb": "server=DBSERVER;user=myuser;password=pwd;database=DB"
  }
}
```

That said, if you do have a `DbConnection` (or `MySqlConnection`) object, you can get the password from the `MySqlConnection.ConnectionString` property if one or both of the following are true:

- The connection has never been opened.
- The original connection string contains `PersistSecurityInfo=true;`. (For more information on this, see the documentation at https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/.)

If you're able to modify the original connection string your application is using, you can add the `PersistSecurityInfo=true` flag. Otherwise, you will need to get an unopened database connection in order to retrieve the full connection string, including the password.